# Use of "neither / nor" with "aren't"

Tags: negation, neither-nor

> We are**n't** able to **neither** preview it **nor** upload it.

Can I use this above sentence? Is this sentence formation correct?

Comment: This is a double negation. Basically this for me means literally "We are able to preview it and upload it". I think you want this: "Neither are we able to preview it nor upload it".

Comment: The idiomatic phrasing would be "We are able neither to preview nor upload it."

Comment: Double negation is a concept from logic but as we surely know no language spoken by humans is necessarily confined by the rules of logic. "Nobody round here don't know nothing, nohow" is a logical mess, but its meaning is quite clear. So in my view double negation on its own is not enough to kill any particular colloquial usage. In this case, the problem is not the double negation, but the simple fact that no native speaker would ever say it.  I think a native speaker would say "We can't preview it or upload it".